# How do I do a blank slot in a functor

Tags: spacing

I want to TeX a blank in the input of a function, to mean that any input can go in there. Specifically, I want to have a tensor product symbol followed by a hyphen `-`.

I have been typing `$\otimes -$` but this is obviously the wrong way to do it since the dash is all over the place depending on the length of the line etc.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not following *the dash is all over the place*

Comment: I usually define `\newcommand{\blank}{{-}}` for this purpose. Depending on coauthors' preferences, it's easy to change `-` into, say, `\,\cdot\,`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Minus sign by default is a binary operator and so will have additional spacing, but this will depend on adjacent atoms so that for example `$1-2$` will have space added but `$-2$` the `-` is assumed to be a prefix unary minus and no space is added.

If you want to use `-` as an ordinary symbol denoting a placeholder, you want a `\mathord` not a `\mathbin` the simplest way to get that is to use `{-}` where the additional brace group is enough to force mathord behaviour.

Comment: Just make sure is it held in a macro what can be redefined in the preamble. Some users use `{}\cdot{}`